# Different answers in recovering C codes from assembly code in ATT

Tags: c, assembly

CSAPP exercise 3.18 requires to recover C codes with assembly codes,
answers the book gives are filled in the blank; the answers in comment is my answers.
C codes as follow:

```
int test(int x ,int y)
{
    int val=_x^y__;  //x-y
    if(_x<-3__){
        if(_x>y_) val=_x*y_;
        else val=_x+y;
             }
    else if(_x>2_)     //x<=2
        val=__x-y__;    //x^y
    return val;
}
```

assembly codes as follow:
[image]

according to the skill the book tells before, i think my answer is right.

Answer (score 2):

The comments in the code (your answers) would result in exactly the same result as the actual code, so they are both correct.

If we ignore the `x < -3` part, the two versions are:

Book version:

```
int val=x^y;
if (x>2)
    val=x-y;
```

Your version:

```
int val=x-y;
if (x<=2)
    val=x^y;
```

Since the `if` condition is switched as well as the assignments to `val`, it's easy to see that at in both cases, `val` will have the value of `x^y` if `x<=2`, and `x-y` if `x>2`.